# Import a library of Python's standard distribution using Brython 3.7.5 into Angular8 project

Tags: python, python-3.x, angular, angular8, brython

I'm doing the first experiments with Angular and Brython. Everything started working, then strangely Python's standard libraries were not recognized. I'm curious to know why.
This is the html part (*index.html* in angular8):

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HelloWorld</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body onload = "brython()">
        <app-root></app-root>

        <script type="text/python">
            import os
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

These are the scripts linked in the *angular.json* file

```
"scripts": [
    "src/assets/js/script.js",
    "src/assets/js/brython.js",
    "src/assets/js/brython_stdlib.js"
]
```

Why, despite linking (presumably) Python's `stdlib`, the treceback remains:

> `ImportError: No module named os`

Did I forget to put something else, or is this problem unsolvable? In the sense that you can't use Brython in angular8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the search mechanism described in the https://brython.info/static_doc/en/faq.html is failing:

> Q : I see a lot of 404 errors in the browser console when I run
>   Brython scripts, why is that ?
>
> A : this is because of the way Brython implements the "import"
>   mechanism. When a script has to import module X, Brython searches for
>   a file or a package in different directories : the standard library
>   (directory libs for Javascript modules, Lib for Python modules), the
>   directory Lib/site-packages, the directory of current page. For that,
>   Ajax calls are sent to the matching urls; if the file is not found,
>   the 404 error message is written in the browser console, but the error
>   is caught by Brython which goes on searching until it finds the
>   module, or raises ImportError if all paths have been tried with no
>   result

which implies the installation is not quite right. Did you check the console for errors?

There is a page which [describes the expected layout](https://brython.info/static_doc/en/import.html); in short, the rules are very similar to the rules for normal Python.

Comment: "You're Goddamn right!" cit. I've solved my problem! When I'll have some time available I will post the complete answer!

Comment: Would you care to explain briefly how you solved the problem? I have excactly the same issue and can't figure it out.

Comment: @Johncowk it has been a while, but IIRC, I watched the URLs being searched using the "developer" tab in the browser for network traffic, and then moved stuff around on disk until the files were found.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for me

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BrythonAngular</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!--  Brython imports-->
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.9.3/brython.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.9.3/brython_stdlib.js">
</script>
</head>
<body class="mat-typography" onload = "brython()">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/python">
  import os
  print(dir(os))
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```